# Linq Orderby compares with itself. Why?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sorting

**Summary:** when using Linq OrderBy with a comparer, I see that OrderBy compares items with themselves `Compare (x, x)`, and I see that it compares the same items `Comparer (x, y)` several times.

- Why does OrderBy `Compare (x, x)`?
- Why does OrderBy compare the same item several times?

---

### Problem description

If you have a (possibly empty) sequence of items, and you want the largest one, you could use `OrderBy(...).FirstOrDefault()`.

I thought, it would be a waste of processing power to Order thousands of items if you will only be using the largest one. You could try to find this largest element in one enumeration, by creating some kind of `Max` method.

Similarly, if you search for the largest few elements: why order all items?

I heard someone say, that if you use OrderBy and take only the first element, then not the complete sequence is ordered.

So I thought to create a test program, where I order Customers using a Customer comparer. To see which Customers are comparer, the customer comparer writes the Id of the customers to the Console.

```
class Customer
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}

class CustomerComparer : Comparer<Customer>
{
    public override int Compare(Customer x, Customer y)
    {
        int result = Comparer<int>.Default(x.Id, y.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Compare {0} - {1} => {2}", x.Id, y.Id, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The console program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var customers = new[]
    {
        new Customer {Id = 2},
        new Customer {Id = 9},
        new Customer {Id = 6},
        new Customer {Id = 1},
        new Customer {Id = 4},
        new Customer {Id = 7},
        new Customer {Id = 3},
        new Customer {Id = 8},
        new Customer {Id = 5},
    };

    IComparer<Customer> comparer = new CustomerComparer;
    var result = customers.OrderBy(customer => customer, customerComparer).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I run the program I get the following output:

```
Compare 4 - 2 => 1
Compare 4 - 9 => -1
Compare 4 - 5 => -1
Compare 4 - 8 => -1
Compare 4 - 3 => 1
Compare 4 - 6 => -1
Compare 4 - 7 => -1
Compare 4 - 4 => 0
Compare 4 - 1 => 1
Compare 4 - 6 => -1
Compare 4 - 1 => 1
Compare 3 - 2 => 1
Compare 3 - 3 => 0
Compare 3 - 1 => 1
Compare 3 - 4 => -1
Compare 3 - 4 => -1
Compare 3 - 1 => 1
Compare 2 - 2 => 0
Compare 2 - 1 => 1
Compare 4 - 4 => 0
Compare 4 - 3 => 1
Compare 9 - 6 => 1
Compare 9 - 7 => 1
Compare 9 - 9 => 0
Compare 9 - 5 => 1
Compare 9 - 8 => 1
Compare 9 - 9 => 0
Compare 9 - 8 => 1
Compare 7 - 6 => 1
Compare 7 - 7 => 0
Compare 7 - 8 => -1
Compare 7 - 5 => 1
Compare 6 - 6 => 0
Compare 6 - 5 => 1
Compare 7 - 7 => 0
Compare 7 - 8 => -1
Compare 7 - 7 => 0
```

Some strange things is what I see:

- Customer [4] is compared with itself seveal times. This is also for Customers [7] and [6], but not for Customers [8] and [1]
- Customer [4] is compared with Customer [6], and a few comparisons later, Customer [4] is compared with Customer [6] again.
- Customers [3] and [4] are compared twice without any other comparisons in between.
- Double comparison is also for Customers [4] and [1], and a bit later for [4] and [3] but not for the other Customers

Why would this be an efficient sorting algorithm?

Comment: For comparison-based sorting algorithms, comparisons are typically assumed to be cheap (as opposed to rearranging elements). It would of course be possible to weed out redundant comparisons or cache them (trading space for time) but this would typically regress performance. Few sorting algorithms guarantee the *minimum* number of comparisons necessary, as opposed to an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Jeroen Mostert, it is probably comparing elements against itself to make the algorithm simpler, and simplicity can in some cases can improve performance. I would expect sorting algorithms to be fairly well optimized, so I would not worry about a few extra comparisons. Also note that `Orderby` is guaranteed to be stable, and this might place extra restrictions on the algorithm.

To solve the problem of returning the largest value I would suggest creating your own implementation that iterates over the collection and returns the smallest/largest. This is fairly trivial to do. Or use something like [MoreLinq MaxBy / MinBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs)

> I heard someone say, that if you use OrderBy and take only the first element, then not the complete sequence is ordered.

The internal workings of `OrderBy` is not documented. In theory, the runtime could inspect the whole sequence of linq calls and produce optimal code.
**Edit:**

- In .Net core 3.x and later does seem to optimize this to `O(n)` (thanks to Matthew Watson for pointing this out).
- In .Net framework it looks like it will create a EnumerableSorter that ends up doing a quicksort of the entire thing, presumably a stable variant. i.e. `O(n log n)`
- In entity framework the query should be translated to SQL and run thru a query optimizer, probably resulting in `O(n)` (or better) runtime.

Comment: .Net Core 3.x and later definitely does the optimisation where if you are only taking the first item, it is `O(N)` rather than `O(Log(N))` (but only for Linq-to-objects). But as you say, this is not documented so you can't rely on it!

Comment: @Matthew Watson, thank your for the information, that was news to me.